# In ServiceNow, how do I rollback to a pre-"Wait for condition" state in a workflow?

Tags: workflow, servicenow

In my ServiceNow workflow for a catalog item, I have a stage for customer acceptance. When the customer rejects the item, it triggers a workflow event and rolls back the workflow to the point where it's waiting for a state again. Or at least, that's the idea. But no matter what I'm doing, the rolled back workflow skips the "Wait for condition" activity immediately.

[This is a screenshot of the workflow section in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyXVR.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but perhaps the below suggestion can help in similar cases:

The thing wit 'Wait for Condition' is that once it has been evaluated, it will not be checked again until there has been a new update to the record on which the workflow runs.
I assume this could be the cause here, one you roll back, if the record itself does not get updated, it skips that activity. You can easily check if that was the case by adding some activity after the roll back to e.g. set a worknote on the record or just 'run script' with the setForceUpdate() function (this updates the record without changing any fields values).

I'm not 100% sure it is the fix to the above problem as there could be many other factors involved and only small part of WF was posted, but definitely something worth checking. 
I hope you found the solution by now!